# Multiclassing QObject and QThread together

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qthread, qobject

I'm trying to create a set of state machines to handle different tasks in my PyQt project, in the process of handling the way that graphics need to be handled on a single thread, I've created two types of state machines, a `StateMachine` which must inherit `QObject` and a `ThreadedStateMachine` which, to avoid duplicate code, I've had inherit from both `StateMachine` and `QThread`.

Here is my minimally complete code to replicate the problem:

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QThread


class StateMachine(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


class ThreadedStateMachine(StateMachine, QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    t = ThreadedStateMachine()
```

I expected this to work without fail, but instead I receive this exception

```
QObject::connect: No such signal ThreadedStateMachine::started()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/snap/pycharm-community/132/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1758, in <module>
    main()
  File "/snap/pycharm-community/132/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1752, in main
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "/snap/pycharm-community/132/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1147, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/snap/pycharm-community/132/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/home/aaron/.PyCharmCE2019.1/config/scratches/emerson_pmd/new/scratch_7.py", line 15, in <module>
    t = ThreadedStateMachine()
  File "/home/aaron/.PyCharmCE2019.1/config/scratches/emerson_pmd/new/scratch_7.py", line 11, in __init__
    super().__init__()
  File "/home/aaron/.PyCharmCE2019.1/config/scratches/emerson_pmd/new/scratch_7.py", line 6, in __init__
    super().__init__()
  File "/snap/pycharm-community/132/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_monkey_qt.py", line 181, in __init__
    self.started = StartedSignalWrapper(self, self.started)
  File "/snap/pycharm-community/132/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_monkey_qt.py", line 151, in __init__
    self.original_started.connect(self._signal)
TypeError: connect() failed between started() and _signal()
```

What's the correct way to combine the `QObject` and `QThread` classes into a single object?

#### Note

I am currently using `threading.Thread` as a workaround, but I'd like to be able to launch a `QMessageBox` from the other thread, which shows an error:

```
QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QItemSelection'
(Make sure 'QItemSelection' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)
QBasicTimer::start: Timers cannot be started from another thread
```

I believe that using `QThread` would work here.

Comment: That's what I suspected, but I also know that when it comes to instantiating multiclassed threads, the order of which you initialize them can play a big factor. I'm in the process of rewriting my project right now to make it more easily troubleshootable, if you make your comments an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you have a problem PyQt does not allow the double inheritance of 2 QObject, StateMachine is a QObject and QThread is also a QObject(see the [docs](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/qt_interfaces.html)).

I do not think the problem is caused by threading.Thread(), I suspect that this is caused because you are modifying some object that lives in a thread and is not thread-safe, the QObjects are not thread-safe so you must interact with those objects in the thread where they live, and the models are QObject.

Read:

- https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-reentrancy.html
- https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/thread-basics.html